# Android java crash after thread.start

Tags: java, android, multithreading

For some reason my program crashes after finishing the thread.start method. Since this is my first time using Thread I´m totally lost and have no clue what´s going on.

```
    public void countingDown() {

waitingTime = (long) (Math.random() * 1000 + 3000);
button.setText("Wait");
try {
    Thread.sleep(waitingTime);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
button.setText("Press");}
```

And calling the Tread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        countingDown();
                    }
                }).start();
```

I would be really grateful!

My logCat shows the following (sorry for the mess):

> 10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-81
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:869)
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4253)
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10539)
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10494)
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6511)
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3771)
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at week8.handin.Week8Handin.countingDown(Week8Handin.java:59)
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at week8.handin.Week8Handin$1.run(Week8Handin.java:82)
>   10-22 14:59:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: The error would be about accessing the `button` variable is not thread-safe, is there any other thread running dude?

Comment: That is right. You can only acces the button from the main ui thread.

Comment: No other thread is running.

Comment: When you create a new thread, it is different from the main (UI) thread. You can only do UI-related operations such as `button.setText()` in the UI thread (which is the thread that runs when you don't create any other thread).

Answer (score 4):

You are performing an UI operation (`button.setText()`) in thread that is not the main (UI) thread. You need a `Handler` or `AsyncTask` to accomplish that - read [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) for further information on them as well as on the whole 'not in the main thread' stuff - or at least `runOnUiThread()` as does the example below (you need to declare your `button` variable `final` for it to work):

```
public void countingDown() {

    waitingTime = (long) (Math.random() * 1000 + 3000);
    button.setText("Wait");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(waitingTime);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            button.setText("Press");
        }
    });
}
```

Please let us know if you have further questions.

Comment: I notice that casting to CharSequence in my thread causes it to crash.